# Section disappears when update pushed to production

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, errors

I have a question about an issue I've been struggling with. If anyone has any ideas - let me know!

I added a "Theme" select field (with advanced custom fields), to allow the client to choose a "Theme" for the page hero on a specific template. The "Theme" dictates some pre-defined combination of colors for the background, text, and button(s). In the template, if an option to "Hero Theme" is selected, a class corresponding to that option is added to the section, and the colors are all set in css.

content-hero.blade.php

```
@php
  $id                   = get_sub_field('anchor_id');
  $theme                = get_sub_field('hero_theme') ? get_sub_field('hero_theme') : '';
  $bg_image             = get_sub_field('background_image') ? get_sub_field('background_image')['url'] : null;
  $supertext            = get_sub_field('supertext');
  $headline             = get_sub_field('headline');
  $subtitle             = get_sub_field('subtitle');
  $featured_image       = get_sub_field('image');
  $ctas                 = get_sub_field('ctas');
  $bottom_text          = get_sub_field('text_below_cta');
  $bg_color             = !get_sub_field('hero_theme') ? get_sub_field('background_color') : null;
  $light_text           = !get_sub_field('hero_theme') ? get_sub_field('text_color') : null;
@endphp
<section class="{{ $theme }} nm-hero{{ $light_text ? ' light-text' : '' }}{{ $bg_image ? ' has-hero-bg-img' : '' }}" {!! $id ? 'id="' . $id . '"' : '' !!} style="{{ $bg_color ? 'background-color: ' . $bg_color : '' }}">
...
</section>
```

I also added some code into my breadcrumb code, to set the breadcrumbs to white if the Hero Theme has a dark background:

intro-section.blade.php

```
@section('breadcrumbs')
  @php $is_white = false @endphp
  @if ( is_page_template('views/non-member.blade.php') )
    @php $nm_hero = get_field('nm_sections')[0] @endphp

    @if ( $nm_hero['acf_fc_layout'] == 'hero' )
      @php $theme = $nm_hero['hero_theme'] @endphp
      @if ( $theme )
        @if ( $theme == 'theme-blue' || $theme == 'theme-violet' || $theme == 'theme-blue-sky-blue' || $theme == 'theme-blue-yellow' || $theme == 'theme-blue-green' || $theme == 'theme-violet-yellow' || $theme == 'theme-gray' || $theme == 'theme-gray-yellow' )
          @php $is_white = true @endphp
        @endif
      @endif
    @endif
  @endif
  <div class="top-line">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="breadcrumbs{{ $is_white ? ' is-white' : '' }}" style="float: {{ isset($contains_file) ? 'left' : 'none' }}">
```

...

Two things broke when I pushed this code.

First, the hero on all other templates stopped appearing. No error message, just poofed from existence. This issue was resolved when I removed the new breadcrumb code.

Then, the hero for the template I was working on disappeared (ugh). I resolved the issue by removing the updates from `content-hero.blade.php`.

Now I need to push the update again, but I'm not sure how to push it without running into the same problems. I can't replicate it on staging or local sites.

WordPress: 6.2.2
PHP: 7.3
Laravel/Sage

Let me know if you have any ideas / anything to try.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the breadcrumbs part, you may need to open the PHP tag and close it only before the HTML.

Comment: @AhmadWael These files were actually written with a language called Blade, which allows you to use the syntax `@if @else @endif` instead of the more cumbersome `<?php if (condition) { ?><?php } else { ?><?php } ?>`

Comment: I suggest you to put all the logic in the breadcrumbs part to a separate function that returns only the value needed. That way will make it looks simpler to you and also will be easier for maintenance.

Comment: @AhmadWael That's great advice, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not getting an error, if there is no error at all, but just a misunderstanding?

By default, without custom coding, is_page_template() will only work on posts/pages where the Post Meta "_wp_page_template" is set. You can set this value in the Page Attributes Metabox when editing a Post. You can enable this by enabling "page-attributes" through add_post_type_support().

Maybe this Post Meta value is missing on the page's you expect the Hero / Section to show.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something tells me this is probably the answer, but it may be missing some info. When I check my page attribute options, I only see "Parent, Template, and Order." Did you mean something else by that? And it sounds like you're referring to a hook in your answer. Could you add the full hook? Once that's complete, I'll be able to test out this answer and award it the bounty :)

Comment: Hi

_wp_page_template is the meta_key which is stored in the postmeta database. 

The add_post_type_support() is a function that can be called on init e.g. add_action( “init”, “some_function” ); See the official docs for more information about the function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_type_support/. 

If you’re registering a Custom Post Type, you can also set the parameter “supports”. This param expects an array e.g. “title”, “editor”, “post-attributes”, …

Comment: I just checked the WP Core repo.  It seems that the function WP_Theme::get_page_templates() is responsible for showing/hiding the “template” option in the Page Attributes Metabox. Luckily there is a filter available “theme_templates”. Or more specified filters based on Post Type etc… https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_theme/get_page_templates/ I’ll probably go down that road to create options without the template comments.